# I keep getting this error in django. Apparently there is something wrong with my js and urls file

Tags: javascript, django

[01/Nov/2020 11:56:54] "GET /static/js/moviesjs.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1668 
 
[01/Nov/2020 11:56:54] "GET /static/js/moviesjs.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1668

This is the error it's throwing.

This is my js code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#createButton").click(function() {

        var serializedData = $("#createMoviesForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: $("createMoviesForm").data('url'),
            data: serializedData,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response) {
                $("#MovieInfo").append('<div class="card, mb=1" data-id="' + response.movieposts.id + '"><div class="card-body">' + response.movieposts.name_of_movie + '<button type="button" class="close float-right"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></div>')
            }

        })

        $("#createMoviesForm")[0].reset();
    });

    $("#movieInfo").on('click', '.card', function() {
        var dataId = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/movieposts/' + dataId + '/completed/',
            data: {}
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: `404` error means the file doesn't exist. So django/python cannot find the said file, `moviesjs.js`. Now, if you have the file, check if you are entering the correct path in your template. And also, post your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

It is odd that the error message indicates it is a GET request (the first javascript block launches a POST request), yet the URL doesn't fit the second data block.

Make sure the API consumer endpoints are written correctly and their urls registered in your url.py files.

With your django server running locally, try calling the URLs through your browser or with curl until you get a hit.